# AngularJS name collision in Dependency Injection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have two modules (finance2, finance3), and each of them defines a service with the same name (currencyConverter).

If I tell my main module that it depends on just finance2, I can inject the service like this:

```
angular.module('invoice2', ['finance2'])
  .controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) {
```

However, if I want my invoice2 to depend on both modules, which currencyConverter would be injected? The one from finance2 or the one from finance3? I can control my own modules, but my concern is if you rely on other people modules that define factories with the same name. How does angular deal with that?

```
angular.module('invoice2', ['finance2','finance3'])
  .controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The last one loaded/processed will win.**

If your scripts are:

- finance2 (with currencyConverter)
- finance3 (with currencyConverter)

Then you will get finance3's currencyConverter when the dependency for currencyConverter is resolved.

If your scripts are:

- finance3 (with currencyConverter)
- finance2 (with currencyConverter)

Then you will get finance2's currencyConverter when the dependency for currencyConverter is resolved.

Comment: Wow, so this is interesting. What if you are loading external modules and you don't have control on naming??

Comment: I believe this is a known short-coming of angular's current DI framework and they are aware of it, which is part of the reason they are implementing DI differently in version 2.